# Featuretools import error in azure databricks

Tags: python, pyspark, feature-extraction, azure-databricks, featuretools

I would like to test the featuretools functionality in azure databricks notebooks.  However getting the module error  as below

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'featuretools'
```

Source code for featuretools as below.

https://docs.featuretools.com/en/stable/_modules/featuretools/feature_base/features_deserializer.html

Comment: this error looks like you don't have a featuretools installed. are you sure you installed it?

Comment: ah my bad :(.. . !pip install featuretools fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missed to run the pip install

```
!pip install featuretools
```

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has resolved. After 48 hours, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.